# I have a desktop motherboard with hard disks that have matrix raid partitions, is it possible to replace it without reinstalling The OS?

Tags: motherboard

it is a fox conn 915A03-P-8EKRS board

I have to replace it because the system is unstable

but The hard disks are having raid 0 and raid 1 partitions

is it possible to replace it without reinstalling the OS and formatting the hard disks?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, with hardware or firmware RAID you need to replace the controller with one from the same range (preferably the same model exactly so be safest). This may not be possible with a cheap motherboard's firmware RAID controller (as they sometimes chop and change components between models).

With regard to the OS, this depends on your OS. I've swapped out motherboards under Linux a number of times over the years and had no issues at all aside from once when drive enumeration changed due to the different I/O controller but that was easy to fix from a LiveCD. I've never been using hardware or firmware RAID in those cases though (Linux's software RAID, as you would expect of software RAID, survives the change without even noticing it). Windows has traditionally been a lot more trouble in these circumstances, though I'm told newer releases are not quite as prone to completely failing (if you can get to safe mode, you can usually recover everything else by downloading the relevant drivers via another machine).

So in your case, other than getting exactly the same motherboard, the only thing you can do to be sure is make sure your backups are up-to-date and try it.